# how to assign numbers to values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

lets say i have a dataframe

```
A     B     C                 D
john  I     agree           Average
ryan  II    agree           agree
rose  V     strongly agree  disagree
Shawn VI    disagree        agree
```

what i want to do is to assign numbers to C column values like this ?

```
A     B     C  D
john  I     1  3
ryan  II    1  1
rose  V     2  0
Shawn VI    0  1
```

i can use [map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for single column but if there are more than one column how do i change values to numbers without writing individual for every column (i know i could use for loops but the problem is that how would i apply it in here)

anyone know how to do this?

i tried to use a for loop

```
def assignNumbers(df):


for i in df:

    second= df[i].map({'Average':3, 'Agree':1, 'Disagree':0, 'Strongly Agree':2})

return second
```

Comment: If you have a dicionary of `codes = {'agree': 1, 'disagree': 0}` etc... then you could try... `df.replace(dict.fromkeys(['C', 'D'], codes)`...

Comment: Or are you asking if there's a way to automatically generate unique codes for the text in both C and D and then apply that?

Comment: Jon Clements no, for agree :1 , disagree: 0, Average :3 like that the problem is if there is more columns like column C and D how can i do it without writing map for all the columns. i was thinking to apply like for loop but the problem is how to loop trough all the column and rows.

Comment: Then you do set `codes` such that it's got the mapping values you want and then adjust the `.fromkeys(...)` to be the column names you want to apply it to as per my first comment?

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be done with scikit-learn's [Label Encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

```
le = LabelEncoder()
df['C'] = le.fit_transform(df['C'])
```